# Python global name 'choice3' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code based adventure game for a class and keep getting an error message saying "global name 'choice3' is not defined". I'm extremely new at coding so I'm probably doing a lot wrong in my code, I'm just not sure what the problem is.

```
      def adventuregame():
            global choice1
            global choice2
            global choice3
            global choice4
            global choice2a
            global choice3a
            global choice4a
            print 'You are locked in a maximum security prison.'
            print 'You have a life sentence here and you want to escape.'
            print 'You’ve been considering ways to escape but you aren’t sure the best way to do it.' 
            choice1 = input('''Should you: 
            1 = Get some guys together and make a plan to fight the guards
            2 = Stick to yourself and make a plan to get out yourself
            Choice: ''')
            if choice1 == 1:
                print 'After talking to a few guys, you assemble a trustworthy team. Word gets around, and someone wants to join the plan that everyone seems to trust, but you don’t know him very well.'
                choice2 = input('''Should you:
                1 = Let him join
                2 = Don't let him join
                Choice: ''')
            if choice1 == 2:
                print 'You’re gonna have to figure a way out yourself. You could pickpocket a guard and get a key to your cell, or you could try and unlock the air vent in your room.'
                choice2a = input('''Should you:
                1 = Steal a key
                2 = Unlock the airvent
                Choice: ''')
                global choice2a
            elif choice2 == 1:
                print 'You trust your friends word and let him in on the plan. It’s probably a good idea to let him join, the more manpower the better.'
                print 'You and the team are discussing various ways of attacking. You get 2 periods a day of free time in the yard. During the morning there are less guards, but during the night it’s all newer guards that got stuck with the night shift.'   
                choice3 = input('''Should you:
                1 = Attack during the day
                2 = Attack during the night
                Choice: ''')
            if choice3 == 1:
                print 'You give the signal and attack. Even though there are less guards, it was still a brutal fight and you and one other person are the only ones to actually make it, and barely.'
            if choice3 == 2:
                print 'You give the signal and attack. The guards are surprised by what is happening, and not thinking clearly, don’t signal for other guards to come. Everyone makes it out before more guards arrive.'
            if choice3 == 1 or 2:
                print 'Once outside the prison, you have some choices on where to go. You can either blindly go through the woods for coverage and hope you come out somewhere, or follow along the river to where you know a town is.'
                choice4a = input('''Should you:
                1 = Go through the woods
                2 = Follow the river
                Choice: ''')
            elif choice2 == 2:
                print '''The guy rats you out to the guards and you get put in solitary confinement for a week, ruining your plans to escape. 
                GAME OVER'''
                restart = input('Type 1 to restart: ')
            if choice2a == 1:
                print '''You try and pickpocket a guard when he isn’t paying attention. You almost get away with it, but another guard notices and takes you down. You get put in solitary confinement and your plans of escaping are ruined. 
                                GAME OVER'''
                restart = input('Type 1 to restart: ')
            if choice4a == 2:
                print 'The guards sent out police helicopters, and you and your team are spotted and caught within an hour. GAME OVER'
                restart = input('Type 1 to restart: ')
            if choice4a == 1:
                print 'After several days in the woods, you come out to a small town. You use a payphone and call one of your friends that will help get you some money and out of the country. YOU WIN'
                restart = input('Type 1 to play again: ')
            if choice2a == 2:
                print 'You manage to get the air vent open, but you aren’t sure where any of the tunnels lead. You could just go for it and hope you find a way out, or you could wait until tomorrow and try and bribe a janitor for a map of the building.'
                choice3a = input('''Should you:
                1 = Try and find a way out
                2 = Bribe a janitor
                Choice: ''')
            if choice3a == 1:
                print 'You decide to risk it and hope you find a way out. After several hours of searching, you get lost and can’t even make it back to your room. You’re caught the next morning and put in solitary confinement. GAME OVER'
                restart = input('Type 1 to restart: ')
            if choice3a == 2:
                print 'After convincing a janitor to give up a map of the building in exchange for some contraband, you know exactly how to get out of the building. That night you make your escape.'
                print 'Once outside the prison, you have some choices on where to go. You can either blindly go through the woods for coverage and hope you come out somewhere, or follow along the river to where you know a town is.'
                choice4a = input('''Should you:
                1 = Go through the woods
                2 = Follow the river
                Choice: ''')
            if choice4a == 1:
                print 'After several days in the woods, you come out to a small town. You use a payphone and call one of your friends that will help get you some money and out of the country. YOU WIN'
                restart = input('Type 1 to play again: ')
            if choice4a == 2:
                print 'The guards sent out police helicopters, and you and your team are spotted and caught within an hour. GAME OVER'
                restart = input('Type 1 to restart: ')
            if restart == 1:
                adventuregame()
```

Comment: If you have that many globals in your code you might want to rethink your design, you should also discover `elif` and `while` loops

Comment: You never assigned anything to choice3...

Comment: You assign `choice3` inside an `if` block, but call the value of `choice3` later. If the code never entered the block, it will not have an assigned value. The only way it will have a value is if `choice2 == 1`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I don't need the code to have a value unless 'choice2 == 1'. Even when 'choice2 == 1' it still gives me an error message that choice3 is not defined.